# How to use "/" (forward slash) in string?

Tags: string, shell, applescript, perlscript

I want to use "/" (forward slash) in string in script but I am getting following error.

I have following applescript to replace content in file.

```
Syntax: do shell script "perl -pi -e 's/oldtext/newtext/g' " & quoted form of (POSIX path of file)
```

Following code is working because there is not special symbol.

```
do shell script "perl -pi -e 's/myname/yourname/g' " & quoted form of (POSIX path of file_tgt)
```

But following code is not working as it has "/".

```
do shell script "perl -pi -e 's/</b>/&lt;/b&gt;/g' " & quoted form of (POSIX path of file_tgt)
```

above code contain `</b>` throws following error:

```
Expected “"” but found unknown token.
```

if I add `<\/b>`, it throw following error.

```
Unknown regexp modifier "/b" at -e line 1, at end of line
Search pattern not terminated at -e line 1.
```

Can anybody please suggest a solution to me?

Comment: `do shell script "perl -pi -e 's/</b>/&lt;/b&gt;/g' " & quoted form of (POSIX path of file_tgt)`. You still have one `/` at `/b`. Try escaping that one as well.

Comment: And maybe the one at `/g` as well.

Comment: @Justplayit94 I appologies but I am not getting your meaning. Can you please modify the line of `do shell script......`?

Comment: `do shell script "perl -pi -e 's/<\/b>/&lt;\/b&gt;\/g' " & quoted form of (POSIX path of file_tgt)`

Comment: @Justplayit94 I am getting this error `Expected “"” but found unknown token.` It highlights "/" symbol in `<\/b>`. Please suggest

Comment: @Justplayit94 This code is working because it doesn't have "/". do shell script "perl -pi -e 's/<b>/&lt;b&gt;/g' " & quoted form of (POSIX path of file_tgt)

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? It looks like you're writing to escape HTML. There are already ways to do this, e.g. https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Escape

Comment: Or he has to surround it like this : `"</b>"`

Comment: @Justplayit94 It's done. I need to replace `</b>` with `<\\/b>` and it worked. Thank you for your efforts.

Comment: Seriously? Nice job!

Comment: Please post your answer so that it help other people in the future.

Comment: @TomFenech: Yup. [See also.](http://weblogs.asp.net/alex_papadimoulis/408925) What are the chances OP's AppleScript is dozens of lines of `do shell script` commands, each one substituting a single hardcoded HTML tag? OP should consider amending his original question to describe _what_ he wants to achieve (e.g. "How do I escape all HTML tags in text…") and _why_ (e.g. "so I can show raw HTML code in a webpage?"), not just _how_ he's currently trying to do it (which might be appropriate to his particular problem, or the worst conceivable way to do it – but we can't tell which without more info).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer.

```
do shell script "perl -pi -e 's/<\\/b>/&lt;\\/b&gt;/g' " & quoted form of (POSIX path of file_tgt)
```